# Login in PHP web application, using Google Apps login for some other domain

Tags: php, authentication, google-oauth

I am working on a PHP web application. I have been given a task to implement login with Google Apps login, for some other domain.

Our PHP application is at `www.myapp.com`. Until now we are using login with emails from our domain only, like `user@myapp.com`. We simply have a users table from which we check combination of email and password and after successful login, we put user id and user name in session. Then from that user name, we get customer id and domain, from customers table. This customer id drives the rest of the application.

From now, we need to implement login with google apps for some other domain. For example, an other domain, say `www.otherdomain.com` is using Google Apps. `www.otherdomain.com` is already a customer of our. In our PHP application (on `www.myapp.com`), we need to add functionality in which user can login with email from `www.otherdomain.com`, like `user@otherdomain.com`. After successful login, we need to get domain from email and get customer id, using domain, from customers table.

Answer (score 2):

I found it, it is called federated login with google apps account.